# Trying to pass a FOREIGN KEY of type date is throwing an error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE festival
(
    title text,
    place text,
    sdate date,
    edate date,
    PRIMARY KEY (title)
);
```

Now, I would like to create another table which would use "title" and "edate" from the festival table.

```
CREATE TABLE event
(
    title text,
    edate date,
    etime time,
    FOREIGN KEY (title, edate) REFERENCES festival (title, edate),
    PRIMARY KEY (title, edate, etime)
);
```

I am getting an error:

> there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "festival"

If I only try to pass the title as a foreign key, then it works, however, if I only try to pass the edate as a foreign key, then it fails (meaning the issue is in "edate" for some reason).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A foreign key relationship should link to the primary key of another table.  So, you should not have `edate` in the definition:

```
FOREIGN KEY (title) REFERENCES festival (title),
```

There is no reason to repeat `edate` in the two tables, if they are supposed to be the same.  Just keep it in `festival` and look it up using a `join`.

I would also recommend that you change festival to be:

```
CREATE TABLE festival (
    festivalId serial primary key,
    title text unique,
    place text,
    sdate date,
    edate date
);
```

That is, introduce a synthetic key which can be used for foreign key relationships.  Declare `title` to be unique.  And then use `festivalId` in the `events` table to get both the title and the date.

Note:  This assumes that the primary key on `festival` should only be on title.  If it is on `(title, edate)`, basically the same logic holds.  In fact, just introduce `festivalId` and use that to look up all information about the `festival`.

Comment: Thank you very much, how silly of me. I am doing a university assignment and I read it wrong. edate should really not have been imported from the festival table. Great to know what foreign key is really used for, that information was really helpful. Unfortunately I cannot change the festival table as it is defined in my assignment, but just to expand my knowledge.. Why would you suggest that I add "unique" to the "title"?

Comment: Actually, you do want dates and times in your event table.  Consider a 1 day event in a 7 day festival.

Comment: @DanBracuk I do want it, you are correct, but it should not be imported as a foreign key from another table.

Comment: @KfirCohen . . . You have `title` has a primary key, which enforces a unique constraint.  My suggestion is to use a synthetic primary key, while keeping the unique constraint.

Comment: "_A foreign key relationship should link to the primary key of another table._" - in general it is wrong, not only to the primary key but to any field(s) with unique constraint.

Comment: @Abelisto . . . Note the word "should".  Foreign key relationships *should* be to primary keys.  They are allowed to other unique keys in all databases.  Some databases even allow relationships to non-unique keys.